# java split unknown length of string in every 3 parts

Tags: java, string, split

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String brandmodel="VolkswagenGolf";
    String [] splitedstring=new String[13]
        //how to insert every 3 letters in splitedstring array
```

}

What i want is to split the above string in every 3 letters.
For example 
i want to save from the above string the next
Vol,ksw,age,nGo,lf
i have read here some crazy codes but i did not understand them,i want the simplest way.
I have not learned Regex yet

Comment: what have you tried? This is really a very simple problem that should not involve any "crazy codes".

Comment: You shouldn't need regex at all.  Look into String's length() and String's substring() method.

Comment: i have to say that the string length is unknown

Answer (score 5):

1. Calculate the number of parts you will have and create an array:

   ```
   int parts = (string.length() + 2) / 3;
   String splitted[] = new String[parts];
   ```
2. Fill the array, using [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < parts; ++i)
   {
       int x = i * 3;
       splitted[i] = string.substring(x, Math.min(string.length(), x + 3));
   }
   ```

Substring takes a string out of another string, using indices.
The problem is that if you take a range that goes out of the string, an exception will be thrown. So what I do, is limiting the endIndex to the string length, by using `Math.min(int, int)`. It will always return the smallest of the two passed values.

Example of this going wrong, without Math.min():

```
String str = "test";
String substr = str.substring(2, 9);
```

This fails (Exception) because, 9 is out of the range of `str`. `str` is only 4 characters long. So, valid startIndices are: {0, 1, 2, 3} and valid endIndices are in this case: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

Comment: Yeah, that's amazing how the two answers came out nearly the same, give or take a few variable names. I love the regex solution a lot, though.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux why we need to find the min, shouldn't we say splitted[i] = string.substring(x,x + 3);  ? please edit your answer with info of my question and i will mark you as the answer

Comment: @user1417426: I added extra explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex look-behind matching the last match plus any 3 characters:

```
String[] splitString = brandmodel.split("(?<=\\G...)");
```

The regex `(?<=\G...)` matches an empty string that has the last match `(\G)` followed by three characters `(...)` before it `((?<= ))`

Output:

```
[Vol, ksw, age, nGo, lf]
```

Comment: +1 this is very good :) The answer would strongly benefit from a brief explanation behind the magical regexp and the relatively lightly-used `\\G` marker of the previous match.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "crazy code" required, it's a relatively straightforward:

```
String[] res = new String[(s.length()+2)/3];
for (int i = 0 ; i != res.length ; i++) {
    res[i] = s.substring(3*i, Math.min(3*i+3, s.length()));
}
```

On ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/J6QhRp).

Comment: Nice to see that we would write it exactly the same way :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for all length of String

```
       String brandmodel="VolkswagenGolf";
       List <String> splitedstring = new ArrayList<String>();
       int i = 0;
       while(brandmodel.length() > 2 )
       {
           splitedstring.add(brandmodel.substring(0,3));
           brandmodel = brandmodel.substring(3);
       }
       if(brandmodel.length() > 0)
           splitedstring.add(brandmodel);
```